# Getting a call to a job and a result of a complex select in a single procedure in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have an SSIS job, and a relatively complex select, that use the same data. I have to make it so that my client doesn't have to call them separately, but use one thing to get the result of the select and call the job.

My original plan was to create a procedure, which will take necessary input, and then output a table variable with the select result.

However, after reading the Microsoft documentation, I found out that table variables might not be able to hold a result with more than 100 rows, while I might want to select ~10 000 rows. And now I'm stumped. What is the best way to call a job and select data, from one component?

I have permissions to create views, procedures, and I can edit the SSIS job. The user will provide me with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would suggest that you do in this scenario, to take the complexity away from the SSIS.

1. Create the SP that you wanted to; but instead of Table Variable; push your output into a table. This table can be addded on the fly(dynamically using CREATE TABLE script) or can exist on the DB always available as a buffer.
2. Call this SP in your control flow.
3. In the Data flow task, select from this buffer table.
4. After completing the SSIS work, flush the buffer table, i.e. truncate the table.

**Caveat:** You may face problem in concurrency scenarios; To eliminate that, you should have a column `BatchID` or `BatchStartTimeStamp` which can store a unique value for each run.

You can pass data for `BatchID` or `BatchStartTimeStamp` from SSIS package.

Comment: There is a part I don't understand - how will anyone be able to get the data from the table, if It will be flushed nearly immediately?

Comment: @Xyzk The buffer table exists to solve your problem for storing/passing large number of rows w/o getting into SSIS. The table is flushed after you are done with consuming the intermediate rows into SSIS.